# check Page Variables inside getStaticProps in nextjs

Tags: next.js

I'm using Next.js with Javascript and I need to check a page variable inside a getStaticProps function.
ex. for the website `https://.../page?id=1` I have to read the id variable.

if it's possible, I'd like to use the next/router library.

Comment: You can't access query parameters inside `getStaticProps` as it runs on the server at build time. You have to access the query param on the client-side instead.

Answer (score 0):

getStaticProps will have access to the context object inturn will have query object in it `async getStaticProps(context){.... const {id} = context.query ....}`
or you can use

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'  
const router = useRouter()
const { pid } = router.query
```

if you are using dynamic routes for each [id].js page

Comment: `getStaticProps` context object does not have access to the `query` object (you may be confusing it with `params`, which is not the same thing). See https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-props#context-parameter.

Comment: How can i set the params with router.push ?